# document.getElementById() does not find anything ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, progress-bar, getelementbyid

Hello I'm creating a progerss bar using ReactJS but I have a problem

My progress bar is going to be a React component and I will pass the progress value in the props

For some reason it seems like document.getElementById() does not find anything

```
import './MyProgressBar.css'

const MyProgressBar = (props) => {
    
    const value = props.value

    const progressbar = document.getElementById("hello");

    progressbar.style.width = value + "%"


    return (
        <div class="progress">
            <div id="hello" class="color"></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyProgressBar
```

It throws an error that says "Cannot read property 'style' of null  at MyProgressBar (MyProgressBar.js:9)....."

Comment: Code run at the top level of the component is evaluated before the DOM is ready, if you *must* use direct manipulation wrap it in a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) or [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), but you should really be leveraging React for reactive changes.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the error is that the element doesn't exist yet as of when you go looking for it. You *could* "fix" that with a `useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect` callback, but that wouldn't be the React approach. Your component will be called to re-render when the props change, so handle rendering in the new state directly:

```
const MyProgressBar = ({value}) => {
    return (
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="color" style={{width: value + "%"}}></div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

This also has the advantage that you can have multiple `MyProgressBar` instances in the page at the same time.

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const MyProgressBar = ({value}) => {
    return (
        <div className="progress">
            <div className="color" style={{width: value + "%"}}></div>
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [bar1, setBar1] = useState(0);
    const [bar2, setBar2] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const t1 = setInterval(() => {
            setBar1(b1 => {
                if (b1 < 100) {
                    ++b1;
                    return b1;
                }
                clearInterval(t1);
                return b1;
            });
        }, 200);
        const t2 = setInterval(() => {
            setBar2(b2 => {
                if (b2 < 100) {
                    ++b2;
                    return b2;
                }
                clearInterval(t2);
                return b2;
            });
        }, 400);
    }, []);

    return <div>
        <div>
            Every 200ms:
            <MyProgressBar value={bar1} />
        </div>
        <div>
            Every 400ms:
            <MyProgressBar value={bar2} />
        </div>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.color {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.progress {
    height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is running before there is anything on the DOM.

You can use it inside a useEffect, running after the render.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const value = props.value
    const progressbar = document.getElementById("hello");
    progressbar.style.width = value + "%";    
  }, [props.value]);
```

You can also use useRef

Answer (score 2):

**You `document.getElementById` is run before actual rendering, so it could not find any element with that Id**

It's not reccomend to use `document.getElementById` in your Reactjs code, use `useRef` instead:

```js
function App() {
  const divRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
console.log(divRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
<div class="progress">
  <div ref={divRef} id="hello" class="color"></div>
</div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained earlier `document.getElementById` won't work in case of react. Because it is running before actual DOM is being created.

- First method is to use `useEffect`

```
   import './MyProgressBar.css'
   import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
   
   const MyProgressBar = (props) => {
       const [progressbarWidth, setProgressbarWidth] = useState(0)
       useEffect(() => {
           const value = props.value
           setProgressbarWidth(value) 
       }, [props.value])
   
       return (
           <div class="progress" style={{ width: `${progressbarWidth}%` }}>
               <div id="hello" class="color"></div>
           </div>
       )
   }
   
   export default MyProgressBar
```

- Second method is to use `useRef`

```
   import './MyProgressBar.css'
   import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
   
   const MyProgressBar = (props) => {
       const progressbarRef = useRef()
       useEffect(() => {
           const value = props.value
           progressbarRef.current.style.width = value + "%" 
       }, [props.value])
   
       return (
           <div class="progress" ref={progressbarRef}>
               <div id="hello" class="color"></div>
           </div>
       )
   }
   
   export default MyProgressBar
```

Answer (score 0):

In react you don't have to access elements by id.

I encourage you to do something like this:

```js
import './MyProgressBar.css'

const MyProgressBar = (props) => {
    
    const value = props.value

    return (
        <div class="progress">
            <div style={{width: `${value}%` }}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyProgressBar
```

Comment: You can certainly have access to elements by id. I do it all the time.

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh Yes you can but it is not the "react" way to do these things, at that point you can just use vanilla js.